# How to configure static IP in Genymotion emulator via adb?

Tags: adb, networking, genymotion

I need to configure Genymotion emulator (Android backed by VirtualBox). I need to setup static IP for eth0. The full list of commands i need to apply:

```
su

ifconfig eth0 10.152.152.12 netmask 255.255.192.0

ip rule add from all lookup main pref 0

busybox route add default gw 10.152.152.10

ndc resolver setnetdns 100 localdomain 10.152.152.10
```

I use adb that is included in Genymotion tools.

`adb devices` shows that device 192.168.8.101:5555 is connected

`adb -s 192.168.8.101:5555 shell` let me enter the shell. I can run ifconfig in that shell - it will show that eth0 is assigned 192.168.8.101.

But entering the first command from list:
`ifconfig eth0 10.152.152.12 netmask 255.255.192.0` hangs the window with Android screen (opened when I started VM) and closes adb session and

`adb devices` shows that `192.168.8.101:5555 offline`

I guess that I've changed IP that is used by adb to control emulator device - therefore I lost the control of VM (both the console/screen of Android and adb session). So I tried some other way to start adb session using `adb usb` that shows output: `restarted to usb`
But `adb devices` after that shows that connected device has IP 192.168.8.101 nevertheless.

**How can I both preserve control over emulator VM and change to needed static IP with ifconfig?**

**Updated:**
I added additional network adapter in VirtualBox's Network Settings (Internal network). That is I added additional interface because eth0 is used for adb connection and likely for displaying Android console/screen launched by Genymotion manager.

Then I invoked aforementioned list of commands but for `eth2` (not `eth0`). The last command `ndc resolver setnetdns 100 localdomain 10.152.152.10` says `500 0 Command not recognized` - I see that different versions of Android have different flavor of this command. So, It works - ipleak.net shows Tor IP, not mine. But - the settings are restored to factory settings after restart and DNS may reveal my IP(since `ndc resolver` fails). So now I need to make commands persistent and apply the last `ndc resolver` command. The version of Android is 12

Comment: adb is unaware of the IP a device has. You have manually told adb to connect via IP 192.168.8.101:5555 and so it does. If you change the IP of the device adb does not recognize and of course still tries to use the old address. And it will continue to do so unless you tell adb to do otherwise.

Comment: @Robert This is what I explained and my question about: how to connect to emulated device so that changing the IP doesn't impact adb connection - I tried USB but likely I do something incorrectly. I need to connect using not IP or not eth0 interface

Comment: Besides - this is not SDK adb - it is from Genymotion Tools. SDK docs say that it's possible to connect via WiFi. But I do not see how to do this in Genymotion. And even if I find the way to connect adb via WiFi - how to force Genymotion console to change the way it is connected - I mean Android screen  - it also hangs when changing eth0 IP. I do not see necessary settings in Genymotion

Comment: I don't think that you can use USB connection to talkt to the emulator. Not sure why you want to change the emulator's IP but have you tried to connect adb using it's new IP address? IMHO you should describe more about why you are trying to change the IP, most likely there is a different way to get what you want.

Comment: There is another way - not using static IP - but it requires configuring Whonix gateway DHCP - - and docs says that this is not tested case.
https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Other_Operating_Systems

Comment: @Robert. I added additional network adapter in VirtualBox Network Settings (Internal network). And invoked aforementioned list of commands but for **eth2** (not eth0).
The last command `ndc resolver setnetdns 100 localdomain 10.152.152.10` says `500 0 Command not recognized` - I see that different versions of Android have different flavor of this command. So, It works - ipleak.net shows Tor IP, not mine. But - the settings are restored after restart and DNS may reveal my IP. So now I need to make commands persistent and apply the last ndc resolver command. The version of Android is 12

Comment: A bit curious why didn't you try installing a terminal app on the emulator and run those commands directly?

Comment: @Andrew T. I believe this will not eliminate the problem with loosing connection after changing IP that is used (likely) for displaying emulator screen - I wrote that after changing eth0 IP this screen has been frozen - hangs. That is window with Android screen has been frozen after IP change of eth0.